# Parallel reading memory mapped file in C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, memory-mapped-files

This is more of a conceptual question. I have been trying to beat the performance of `fread` and stream reading file (1Million+ lines) in C++ which has multiple data types. For example, the file would consist `int`s, `float`s, and `string`s in each line.

After researching, I decided to go memory mapped route so I did `CreateFile`, `CreateFileMapping`, and `MapViewOfFile`. Wrapped whole mapping process around an object to access the pointer to the mapped file so I can call this object and access the mapped file pointer from another function.

I was able to read the file successfully but the performance is NOT as expected. In fact there is no gain than using `fread`. Again I am still reading serially so I believe that is the main issue.

My question is how to go about parallelzing the reading process? I first thought of using `intel TBB` or `openMP` to keep it simple but I believe this could have issues with not properly aligning with line endings etc.,

So the alternative is to use a thread pool and a blocking mechanism and have each thread read a different block of mapped memory. Will this be any help to improve the performance? Any other suggestions if someone have run into  a similar issue? or how to go about doing this in memory mapped files.

I'm also open to other parallel file reading alternatives for Windows in C++.

Comment: Do you know anything about the hardware device on which the file is stored?  For example, if you've got one magnetic hard disk, there's no point trying to parallelise the read as you'll just start seeking more and slow everything down....

Comment: Agreed. If this is a hard disk drive the performance will be worse in parallel than sequential.

Comment: It is a magnetic disk. But I was under the impression that whole purpose of mapping the file to memory is to reduce the disk seek and have it load to the shared memory by OS. And from there we can parallel read from the mapped memory to do the parsing and other tasks for improved performance? please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Remember a disk is better at reading/writing large chunks sequentially. Not small chunks at random. By paralleling you are making the reads / writes small random operations.

Comment: Your bottleneck is the hard drive.  Most hard drives are serial in nature and read bits off the platters using one head (one head per platter).  The faster a platter spins, the faster the data can be retrieved.  If you want parallel performance, you may be able to connect several drives in parallel, example, one 8-bit byte would be dispersed across 8 drives.  Hard drive packages have developed hardware to boost performance.

Comment: One primary issue with reading files is that the data is not in one single continuous stream of bits.  Usually the file data is a linked list of blocks.  The hard drive must spend time seeking to the other blocks, which takes time away from reading the bits.

Comment: A performance hurdle, to your program, is the hard drive having to spin up to speed.  To reduce the likelihood of spin-ups, you want to transfer as much data in one request, as possible.  The thorn against this issue is that there may not be enough memory available (for example, reading an entire file into memory).  Memory mapping works more by request or "on demand".  *Pages* of a file are loaded into memory as needed; not the entire file.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. I guess my best approach is to memory map but force request "demand" blocks to be read in advance from the mapped memory and then process each block in parallel. As of now I should not have a issue with memory (32GB+ avalable) and files can be around 1GB and note more than few of them required at once.

Comment: Alternatively I could demand a block from mapped memory and process the block in parallel and repeat the process till I read the whole file... Any suggestion as to which is more efficient?

Comment: The usual hangup is assuming that the OS is dumb and cannot do what you can do with an MMF.  That is not accurate.  The file system cache is already a terrific MMF implementation.  Modern machines have plenty of RAM to let it do its job efficiently.